# If i have a static property inside a class and make many new instances of that class

Tags: c++, memory, static

If i have a static property inside a class and make many new instances of that class... does the static property only take up 1 slot of memory and yet all other public members take up what they need.

The problem:

```
class Raindrop
{
public:
    Raindrop( ComPtr<ID3D11Device1> d3dDevice );
    ~Raindrop( );

    void Initialize( );
    void Update( );
    void RandomiseXPos();

    float x;
    float y;
    float z;
    float velocity;

    static const unsigned short indices[ 6 ];
    static const VERTEX vertices[ 4 ];

    const ComPtr<ID3D11Device1> d3dDevice;
    ComPtr<ID3D11Buffer> vertexbuffer;
};
```

I want to make many Raindrops have their own x,y,z, velocity and initialise/update/randomiseXPos functions... but the actual vertices and indices of this raindrop... will always be the same for every raindrop made.

By declaring those properties as static... do I in fact prevent memory being created and used x amount of times for each raindrop?

Comment: You know what static means? one instance per *class*?

Comment: so to clarify.. the class itself has one instance of this property.. and no matter how many raindrops I want to make, that 1 property will persist throughout? Negative voting.. interesting? I come from PHP, I thought I had made quite a good attempt at this :( . I look forward to more help.

Comment: I would guess that the downvode comes from not having googled what static means within a C++ class. Any reasonable tutorial/introduction into C++ and classes should explain it reasonably well.

Comment: I used Bing.. perhaps that was my mistake ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> By declaring those properties as static... do I in fact prevent memory being created and used x amount of times for each raindrop?

Absolutely - that is the meaning of `static`. When you need to share an instance of an object among all instances of the class, such as your `indices` and `vertices` arrays, you normally make the shared instances `const` (precisely the way you did) to avoid accidental modification.

Note: In C++ static members need to be defined, in addition to being declared. Therefore, there is a possibility that two separately compiled dynamic libraries that both contain copies of the same class would end up with two separate memory ares containing the static objects. Situations like that rarely happen in practice, so you should be fine.

Comment: Ah, cool man! Thanks for the help... Now I gotta figure out why my application is crapping memory then. thought i'd found the answer.